# Is there a chemical compound, element or something else that could color the eye lens in purple?

Tags: human-biology

I hope this is a right place to ask this question. I'm writing scifi book, and looking for information whether it is possible for any element, chemical compound, radiation or something else to color the human eye lens (and or freckles) to purple.

Comment: slightly related: [Could being exposed to excess UV in the arctic lead to a human eye color change? If so, what is the mechanism?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/76974/27918)

Comment: You meant the iris by writing the lens? Colored lens would lead to partial blindness in chosen part of the spectrum.

Comment: If it's for a sci-fi book, how about genetically engineered (designer baby kind of thing) humans where the humans have a genes inserted to express purple chromophores in their lens or on their skin in melanocytes? It wouldn't be awfully straightforward, but hey, if you can cause organized [fibrillation of lysozyme](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/jacs.7b03056) (a protein normally found in bodily fluids), you can get purple pigment! Also, a purple lens would mean that your purple-lensed character would be impaired in seeing purple.